# How to export testopia test-cases?

Tags: bugzilla, testcase

I'd like to export [Testopia](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/testopia/) test cases in CSV or XML format but the builtin export doesn't allow to have the full test case with steps and results. I have to export for someone who will do tests without an Internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to locate the cgi file, tr_show_case.cgi in the testopia patch bugzilla directory. You could probably export the related format using the link below. With the last link, you should be able to export out a printable format including full test case with steps and expected results.

```
http://<bugzilla_url>/tr_show_case.cgi?case_id=1&ctype=csv 
http://<bugzilla_url>/tr_show_case.cgi?case_id=1&ctype=xml 
http://<bugzilla_url>/tr_show_case.cgi?case_id=1&ctype=print
```